# Any Bash script always gives Command not found

Tags: bash, shell

So I've been trying to run some simple scripts for file management in a OSX 10.9.5 Environment but every time i try to run a script it first says i dont have permission so I sudo the command but then throws a command not found error.

eg;

```
sudo ./hello.sh
```

after inputting my password will result in

```
sudo: ./hello.sh: command not found
```

the hello.sh script consists of this.

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo 'hello world'
```

Yet if i just run the command `echo 'hello world'` from the terminal line then it prints it just fine. 
I have checked for incorrect line endings but they are \n

still a novice in terminal/command line usage so explanations would be amazing.

Comment: Is it executable? `chmod 755 ./hello.sh` first?  (Or `umask 022`.)  You need to set the permission bit before you can execute it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the problem isn't with the permissions on your user account but with the file itself. I just did exactly what you said, and it didn't run, I realized, because the file permissions didn't allow you to run it. Either do

```
chmod +x hello.sh
```

or do

```
sh hello.sh
```

Either of those should work.

Comment: Would generally do `bash hello.sh` instead of `sh hello.sh`, since the question is explicitly tagged `bash`

Answer (score 0):

#### Has the Execute bit

Ensure the file has the execute bit set

```
$ chmod +x hello.sh
```

#### On your system `bash` isn't in `/bin`

You can determine where `bash` is installed on your system with

```
$ type -path bash
```

#### Use `env` to search the path

And you can use `env` to search in your shell script declarations like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```